# Redactor Text Editor – Re-Indent Minified HTML In Code View?

Tags: javascript, redactor, redactor.js

When using the wonderful redactor text editor's code view to write raw HTML, I've programed my application to save drafts on a keypress event.  The HTML is then minified and sanitized on the server side before being saved to the a database, then it is passed to the client side where I set the code back in the text editor using:

```
$('#blogpost-html').redactor('code.set', data.html);
```

However, if the viewer is looking at the code editor, their code gets minified after every change, which results in losing the pretty indentation redactor automatically applies when the code view is first toggled and shown.

I can switch to the text view and then back to the code view to have redact re-apply the pretty indentation to my minified HTML.  I'm wondering if there is a function redact's API exposes that I can call immediately after setting the HTML code to pretty indent it.

[I've been looking, but I can't seem to find anything...](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/api/code/)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the Redactor source code, I found I could simply access their `tabifier` module and re-indent the code myself like this:

```
      var text_editor = $('#post-html').redactor({
            codeKeyupCallback: function(e) {
                var self = this;
                post.html = this.code.get();
                savePostDraft(function(error, saved_post) {
                    self.code.set(self.tabifier.get(saved_post.html));
                });
            }
        });
```